# need to fix mysqli_result code

Tags: php, mysqli

I am new to php so please be gentle.  I have lookup up solutions within this forum on the exact same problem but am a little confused.  I can't seem to figure out why the error

> Call to undefined function mysqli_result() in line 10

keeps occurring.

Can anyone help please

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
$per_page = 10;

$pages_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT('uniqueID') FROM 'business'");
$pages = mysqli_result($pages_query, 0) / $per_page;

$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
$start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;

$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT 'manu' FROM 'business' LIMIT $start  $per_page");
while ($query_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
echo '<p>', $query_row['manu'] ,'</p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: mysqli_result is actually not a function at all but a class. If you are trying to follow some some older tutorial (which has the old mysql_result) then I can understand the confusion.  http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php   `mysqli_fetch_assoc` (which is actually `mysqli_result::fetch_assoc()`) is probably what you really want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
$per_page = 10;

$pages_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT('uniqueID') FROM 'business'");
$result = mysqli_fetch_row($pages_query); // <----- added
$pages = $result[0] / $per_page; // <------- modified

$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
$start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;

$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT 'manu' FROM 'business' LIMIT $start  $per_page");
while ($query_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
echo '<p>', $query_row['manu'] ,'</p>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
$per_page = 10;

$pages_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT('uniqueID') FROM 'business'");
$result = mysqli_fetch_row($pages_query); // <----- added
$pages = $result[0] / $per_page; // <------- modified

$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
$start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT 'manu' FROM 'business' LIMIT $start  $per_page");
while ($query_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

echo '<p>'. $query_row['manu'] .'</p>';

}
?>
```